# Django nginx 502 bad gateway

Tags: django, nginx

I am learing nginx for django, i am running the server in locally with docker.

this is my `django_nginix.conf` file :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name musicaldd.com;

client_max_body_size 90M;

location /media/ {
    root /home/pyking/cpd/musicaldd_back/storage/;
}

location /static/ {
    root /home/pyking/cpd/musicaldd_back/storage/;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://djangoapp:8000/;
}
```

}

When I run the server creating docker images and hit the URLs, it returns me `502-bed getaway timeout | nginix` Can anyone tell me why this errors occuse, how can I fix this error

It may stupid question but this is very serious to me, coz, i am new on Nginx, it will really much be appreciated if you help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using uwsgi add this to your nginx.conf file based on your uwsgi params file location.

```
include   /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass  unix://tmp/uwsgi.sock;
uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /;
```

If you are not i suggest use that. there is another option called gunicorn but uwsgi has better performance.

Comment: i don't recommend using gunicorn but gunicorn will make a socket too. so u have to tell nginx to pass to that. a good tutorial is available https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04